# jQuery AJAX post is changing characters in post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using jQuery post to post checkbox values to another file, I know the page works and the logic is correct because when I'm not using jQuery post the page works fine, problem is it seems to mess with the array and therefore causes it to not work properly

My `radio` field uses these form fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="radio[]" value="<? print $id; ?>">
```

Which when posted to the next page is processed by

```
if ($_POST['radio']){
    foreach($_POST['radio'] as $val) {
```

This is what posts when I get as a normal form submit, using `print_r($_POST);`

```
Array (
    [radio] => Array (
        [0] => 13
        [1] => 12
    )
    [ros] => sell
    [submit] => submit
)
```

That works fine, problem is it doesn't work in jQuery AJAX, so I can process the data without having to refresh, when I post the form using jQuery AJAX, the data looks like this:

```
Array (
    [ros] => sell
    [submit] => submit
    [radio] => radio %5B %5D=15&radio%5B%5D=14&ros=sell
)
```

This is my jQuery AJAX post script:

```
function submitgarage() {
    var submit = $("input[name=submit]").val();
    var ros = $("#ros option:selected").val(); 
    var radio = $("#garageform").serialize();
    $.post("ajax/vehicles/garage.php", { ros: ros, submit: submit, radio: radio },
    function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    });
}
```

As you can see it is adding the `%5B` `%5D` etc, I have attempted to use `utf8_decode`, caused a server 500 error, attempted to use `urldecode`, which I suspected wouldn't work anyway and I was right, I just cant seem to get it to post the same as it did before.

I have checked other topics on Stack Overflow for the same kind of thing and couldn't seem to find a solution.

Comment: As you seem to know, `%5B`and `%5D` are percent-encoded representations of `[` and `]`, respectively. Unfortunately, html and code are missing that would show where in the course of request handling the strings you show exist (client/browser, server; js, php). Please also provide the (non-jquery) code sample that produces the expected result. You might want to try a web proxy like fiddler on your client to check the content of the http messages exchanged between client and server.

Comment: Thanks, ive added the input field and the part of the code that it posts to, thanks

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php  Just decode the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's AJAX serializes the given data object, but you already serialized the radio field, so you get it serialized twice.

Your `radio` variable needs to be an array, not already serialized data.

```
var radio = $("#garageform [name='radio[]']:checked").get().map(function(e) {
    return e.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with parse_str it works pretty good with your example post:

```
parse_str("radio %5B %5D=15&radio%5B%5D=14", $jqarr);
print_r($jqarr); // Only for print array   

Array
(
    [radio_] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
        )

    [radio] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
        )

)
```